# create a Custom Encryption application in python

Tags: python, encryption

Is it possible to create a custom encryption program using python?  I know that most encryption applications use methods like blowfish and AES but what if you wanted to make your own, more secure encryption type?

Comment: Your "custom" encryption algorithm will be insecure. The people who design and analyze encryption algorithms know what they're doing, so unless you know something that they don't, you probably won't be able to come up with anything remotely secure.

Comment: More secure? That would be pretty hard? Is this for a school project or? please give more details.

Comment: I'm sort of curious what ideas Johnny has to improve or why he thinks the standard encryption algorithms are not good enough.

Comment: Maybe downvoting the question is not what we should do here - everyone is entitled to be wrong and learn from their mistakes.

Comment: Downvoting isn't some kind of punishment for being wrong, it just means people don't think the question is a good or useful one.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I wouldn't call a misinformed question a bad question.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily, but I would call a question that assumes a home grown encryption method will be "more secure" a bad question.

Comment: @Blender: +1. But actually, even _those_ people don't really know what they're doing… They key is that they know what they don't know, and they know how to test (and, more importantly, get other people to test) the limits of their knowledge, and so on.

Comment: While we're at it, the biggest security flaws in most crypto software have nothing to do with the crypto algorithm yourself. For example, despite the fact that AES is known to be broken, nobody has ever actually cracked a 256-bit AES key, and it would take decades to do so. However, people _have_ cracked cryptosystems that use AES improperly… and every day, people just walk around the cryptosystem entirely by, e.g., calling someone to ask for the password.

Answer (score 8):

You should not, ever, roll your own crypto.

Just don't.

If you *really* want to get involved in crypto, study it. Learn the math first. Then learn the code.

Coursera has a great class on Cryptography from Stanford professor Dan Boneh. But don't fool yourself, building "more secure" crypto is going to be years of work.

---

To answer your question specifically: Python is not a good fit for crypto, unless the crypto is implemented as a C extension module.

Automated memory management opens up a **lot** of side-channel attacks that you can't really do anything about.

Answer (score 2):

You can take as example of how hard is rolling own cripto from SHA3 challenge.
Keep attention on how most of attendants are skilled cryptanalysis but got there submissions busted.

http://ehash.iaik.tugraz.at/wiki/The_SHA-3_Zoo

If you dont know all of this:
 - Impossible diferential cryptoanalysis
 - XLS attack
 - Side channel attack
 - S-box

Then just do not roll your own. When you will learn all that is needed to design and test algorithm, you will also learn why it is nearly impossible to make secure crypto scheme.